# VB6 crashes after build

Tags: vb6

Visual Basic 6 is crashing after a new build of my program. Whenever I `Start` (F5 or Ctrl-F5) my program after making changes to the code, VB6 crashes with the following message:

> An unhandled win32 exception occured in VB6.EXE [XXXX].

I can't make any pattern out of `XXXX`. It's been 5168, 5012, 1488, etc; it changes every crash.

The JIT debugger then offers to let me debug VB6 in VS2010 (which shows nothing but a bunch of disassembly.) If I say no, VB6 shuts down. I can then open and `Start` my program immediately, and it runs just fine; my changes from before the crash were saved. Alternatively, I can make changes, save them, exit VB6, restart VB6, then run them without a problem. But it seems like as soon as I make any changes, a "crash" flag is set, and if I try and build it before restarting VB6, it simply dies.

I'm only having this problem with specific projects. Most projects work completely normally. It's just this one, and it's branch, that both act in the same manner.

Does anyone have *any* clue what's going on? Obviously, saving works. And building works. And running works. They just don't seem to work together.

---

I reinstalled VB6 to no avail.

Comment: Does it crash when you built the EXE and run the EXE. Can you find out at which point it crashes by going through it with F8? Have you checked the properties of the project for anything strange?

Comment: My bet would be on custom controls that are being used.  You have my sympathies, but that's the most I can offer you.

Comment: *@Jürgen Hollfelder* - F8 crashes in the same manner as F5 - I never enter the program code.

Comment: what version or windows are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up on this page after installing VS2010, and just one of many VB6 project wouldn't compile.

Simply go to Project Properties / Compile tab, and uncheck "Create Symbolic Debug Info".

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I am getting this error during build.  I don't have the property checked.

Comment: @KirstenGreed (or anyone else) you might try to turn the property ON and then OFF again. Just in case its data is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Try to open vb6 project with compability mode as XP. We had some issues related to "make exe" command. Then I started to run VB6.exe with XP compability mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for *any* clues, possible clues may include:

- The surprises VB6 experiences when run on Vista/7. Try running elevated/remove elevation.
- Same, but applied to a third party ActiveX control you're using.
- Not having the Service Pack 6 installed. Install it.
- Subclassing issues. Make sure your subclassing, if any, is actually correct.
- Whatever problems you'll never figure out. Try reinstalling.

Answer (score -2):

Reinstall VB6, delete the workspace files and then create a new project adding in all your current code files. Then go out and get a job where they use a modern SDK :)