# an unhandled win32 exception occurred in VB6.exe during project build

Tags: vb6

I have a legacy VB6 solution with a lot of projects.
I am getting the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409093/vb6-crashes-after-build)  only when building the project.

The error is displayed inside a dialog box with the caption "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger"

I have often got the error before, particularly in the IDE if I move a control on a form that has lots of controls.  Usually the error does not repeat consistently.

However the error is now consistently repeating and preventing me from building.
I have rebooted.

My next step will be to start trying to uninstall other things from my machine.  I particularly suspect dot net framework 4 which might have installed yesterday.

The OS is Windows XP Professional Version 2002 SP3

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Update: uninstalling framework 4 made no difference. 
I opened the solution and pressed F5 to run it,  and got the error.  I opened a form in design mode, then pressed F5 to run and was able to run OK.  I also was able to compile the solution, and then to my relief - to build it.

The trick seems to be to have a form open before I build.

Comment: Scary stuff, legacy systems are hard enough to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick seems to be to have a form open before I build.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the this morning and I noticed that before error pop up, cursor was waiting for control paste (+ mark) on form and toolbox was closed. I opened the tool box(View Menu-> ToolBox) clicked on a form saved the project and error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling without creating debug symbols.  Right click the project and select properties.  Click on the compile tab and uncheck "Create Symbolic Debug Info".

Comment: There are 18 projects in the solution. None of them have this option checked.