# Why does the VB6 IDE crash when opening a form?

Tags: vb6

The question is - why is my VB6 IDE crashing (all of a sudden) and how can I fix it?

VB6 had been operating on this PC, normally, for months if not years before this first began. The problem appeared to arise spontaneously.

Here's all the information I have to describe the issue...

Scenario:

1. Run VB6 - either by double clicking a project (VBP) file, or from it's icon / Start menu
2. Load a project
3. Try to open any form or code module
4. IDE instantly crashes with an error message such as:

> An unhandled win32 exception occured in VB6.EXE [XXXX].

Allowing Windows to open the debugger, it shows the fault occurring on this line:

> 004581F1   mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]

And in the Windows event log, it shows this:

`Problem signature:
 Problem Event Name:    APPCRASH
 Application Name:  vb6.exe
 Application Version:   6.0.97.82
 Application Timestamp: 403acf6c
 Fault Module Name: vb6.exe
 Fault Module Version:  6.0.97.82
 Fault Module Timestamp:    403acf6c
 Exception Code:    c0000005
 Exception Offset:  000afa89
 OS Version:    6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.48
 Locale ID: 1033
 Additional Information 1:  a239
 Additional Information 2:  a239f58f940977df1cec7176d1176bff
 Additional Information 3:  ef99
 Additional Information 4:  ef9908a42708e3d51b1220b5874297f1`

O/S: Win7 64 bit

Note 1 - I think this is a different issue than this question: [VB6 crashes after build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409093/vb6-crashes-after-build), because the scenario to cause the crash is different.

Note 2 - I have seen a few signs of this problem elsewhere. Both [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?516971-RESOLVED-VB6-Can-t-open-project-forms-without-VB6-crashing%20here) and [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/tech-discussions/325980-vb6-ide-crashes-form-view-windows-8-a.html) include some similar information, but no apparent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately I found that I needed to reset the compatibility settings of VB6.exe.

Specifically:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98`
2. Right click `vb6.exe`, right click, and select `Properties`
3. Select Compatibility tab
4. Mine was already set to run in *Win XP compatibility* mode. Uncheck this.
5. Close properties.
6. Run the EXE. **Still not fixed**.
7. Open properties. *Set Win XP compat again*.
8. Run VB6. Open project. Open form. **No crash**.

Note that rebooting, reinstalling VB6 and the latest service pack, etc. had no effect on this issue, all of which I tried before stumbling into this solution.